# You must set the RNG (RandomUtils.Random) before generating random numbers

Tags: c#, .net, bitcoin, blockchain, nbitcoin

I am trying to follow the tutorial [here](https://programmingblockchain.gitbooks.io/programmingblockchain/content/bitcoin_transfer/bitcoin_address.html). My code is as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Key privateKey = new Key(); // generate a random private key
        PubKey publicKey = privateKey.PubKey;
        Console.WriteLine(publicKey); // 0251036303164f6c458e9f7abecb4e55e5ce9ec2b2f1d06d633c9653a07976560c

        Console.WriteLine(publicKey.GetAddress(Network.Main)); // 1PUYsjwfNmX64wS368ZR5FMouTtUmvtmTY
        Console.WriteLine(publicKey.GetAddress(Network.TestNet)); // n3zWAo2eBnxLr3ueohXnuAa8mTVBhxmPhq

        var publicKeyHash = publicKey.Hash;
        Console.WriteLine(publicKeyHash); // f6889b21b5540353a29ed18c45ea0031280c42cf
        var mainNetAddress = publicKeyHash.GetAddress(Network.Main);
        var testNetAddress = publicKeyHash.GetAddress(Network.TestNet);

        Console.WriteLine(mainNetAddress); // 1PUYsjwfNmX64wS368ZR5FMouTtUmvtmTY
        Console.WriteLine(testNetAddress); // n3zWAo2eBnxLr3ueohXnuAa8mTVBhxmPhq

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {    
        throw;
    }   
}
```

However on the first line, I am getting this error:

> You must set the RNG (RandomUtils.Random) before generating random numbers

Comment: So, why have not followed the instructions the error give you.

Comment: not sure how!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize the random number generator the crypto library will use. For testing you can use the `UnsecureRandom` class that comes with the NBitcoin library you are using.

```
RandomUtils.Random = new UnsecureRandom(); // set the random number generator.
Key privateKey = new Key(); // generate a random private key
```